# Dishwasher plug

Tags: electrical

I have a 1959 block home and I'd like to put a dishwasher in one of the cabinets.
Can I tap into an existing outlet wire to install the dishwasher plugin. Or do I have to run a dedicated line to the breaker box. My other idea was to use the wiring on the garbage disposal (hard wired) and just not have a disposal.

HELP!!

Comment: How much current does this dishwasher pull?

Comment: Sharing a circuit with the disposal might be better than a plug that could have a toaster or crock pot on it since it's such an intermittent load.  You still have the issue of overloading if they are both on at the same time - it just might be easier to control.

Answer (score 1):

The electrical code answer would be that it needs a dedicated breaker but a 1959 house probably has a lot of wiring that is not up to modern codes.

If you put it on an existing circuit and the circuit ended up pulling too much load it would trip the breaker.  If you start the dishwasher and it is running and you then plug a toaster oven into an outlet that is on the same circuit - the breaker would trip.

Comment: is correct.  That said, when I did my island, and knowing that you cook before supper generally, and wash dishes after, I put in 4 convenience on the underside of the island countertop.  Two of these share the circuit with the dishwasher.  The other two are on their own circuit.  The ones that share typically run a crock pot, or a laptop charger.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford And when you sell the house and someone else uses those points differently which causes an issue....

Comment: You speak truth.  But I still have 12 plugs on 7 circuits.  Yes, if someone uses a deep fryer while the dishwasher is on, they better use plugs 2 or 4 on the island.  Or one of the plugs on the back counter.  Or one of the plugs on the stove counter.  Or one of the wall plugs.